# Where is it? - The Google Earth Challenge Ep. 2

Tags: visual, geography

Well, Just got instant kill from the first puzzle :P. Let's try harder this time!

This puzzle will provide a screenshot in somewhere on Google Earth, please try your best to identify where the location is. The reasons to find out the location should be part of your answer.

Will give a zoom-out image as the next hint if not be answered yet.

**Note:** It's not recommended to use Google Search by Image function(I'll try my best to avoid that when selecting the screenshot). **Try to use any feature on pixels or your geography knowledge to derive the location.**

---

**Question:**

[image]

Comment: Aliens. It's aliens I tells ya.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I should get no credit for this to speak of, since other people already had all the actual *ideas*, but I am pretty sure this is

> Performance Lake at Wynn Palace, Cotai, Macau: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Wynn+Palace/@22.147735,113.5699791,262m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x340170022935166f:0x1ec9da50495f963c!8m2!3d22.1484549!4d113.5709973

Comment: Yes you got it! I think the puzzle is harder this time :P

Answer (score 8):

Partial Answer: (though quite obvious)

> It's most definitely related to a water show, as it strikes an extremely odd similarity to the Vegas' Fountains of Bellagio, though it doesn't fit the image even when rotated 
>  [image: Fountains of Bellagio]

Comment: Yes, a good start for the derivation!

Comment: [This location](https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Dubai+Fountain/@25.1949749,55.2747106,410m) also looks similar but not exactly the same.

Comment: If you have time, search through [these locations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WET_(company)). Same company that made both the ones we've found that look similar; probably they made another one which is what we're looking for. (I've spent half an hour looking at pics of fountains all over the world, and giving up now.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor nice try!

Comment: You're right, it does really look like the Fountains of Bellagio

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be

> some sort of memorial, and the water looks semi-tropical.

My best guess is

> a construction development in the persian gulf